# Route internet traffic for VMs using a gateway node

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a network `10.20.1.0/24`, configured within a machine, which is to be used by VMs on that machine. The IP on the physical interface of that machine is `172.31.10.94/24`. I am forwarding internet traffic from IP attached to a VM `10.20.1.2/24` at `172.31.10.94/24` to a linux server `172.31.10.2/24` via default route.  The linux server is being used as a gateway here. There is an iproute for `10.20.1.2/24` on the gateway to forward all traffic destined to `10.20.1.2/24` to `172.31.10.94/24`.

ip route on machine hosting the VM:

```
default via 172.31.10.2 dev enp1s0f0 
10.20.1.3 dev tap22-dr2 scope link 
172.31.10.0/24 dev enp1s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.81.94 
192.168.20.0/24 dev enp3s0f0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.20.2 
192.168.20.102 dev tapd29f98b1-44  scope link 
unreachable 192.168.121.0/24  proto bird
```

Here is my ip route on gateway machine

```
default via 172.31.10.1 dev eth1 
10.20.1.3 via 172.31.10.94 dev eth1  proto bird 
172.31.10.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.31.10.2 
192.168.20.102 via 172.31.10.94 dev eth1  proto bird 
192.168.121.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.121.43
```

I’m trying to nat all internet traffic coming from `10.20.1.0/24` to `172.31.10.1` so that VMs on the host machine can get external connectivity. Any help is much appreciated?
[image]

P.S: this was a simple implementation for external connectivity in OpenStack with Project Calico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an easy fix, though I'm not sure if it is the best solution.

```
# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -s 10.20.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Please suggest if there are any better ways.